# Laravel db:seed attempts to seed wrong table

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5.8

I have a relationship between a user & nextOfKin model set up like this

User.php

```
public function nextOfKin()
{
    return $this->hasOne(NextOfKin::class, 'user_id');
}
```

NextOfKin.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I have created the `users` & `next_of_kins` tables using migration and want to add data to the table using database seeding. When I run my `UsersTableSeeder`

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\User::class)->create()->each(function ($user) {
        $user->nextOfKin()->save(factory(App\NextOfKin::class)->make());
    });
}
```

it returns an error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "next_of_kin" does not exist
>   LINE 1: insert into "next_of_kin" ("user_id", "firstname", "lastname...
>                       ^ (SQL: insert into "next_of_kin" ("user_id", "firstname", "lastname", "relationship", "address", "state", "country", "updated_at", "created_at") values (1, Willie, McCullough, family, 3334 B
>   ridget Cliffs, Michigan, Micronesia, 2019-07-03 13:35:48, 2019-07-03 13:35:48) returning "id")

Why is the migration trying to insert into `next_of_kin` instead of `next_of_kins` table? The users table seeding is successful. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you show the model class for NextOfKin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model, you can specify what table to use:

```
class NextOfKin extends Model
{
    protected $table= 'next_of_kins'; 
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is necessary when Laravel can't determine the correct table name to use based on model name and pluralization. Since `kin` is plural, the table Laravel is trying to use is `next_of_kin`.